# How to delete referenced collection id in my node.js mongodb based application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Comment Model, User Model and Post model. In Post Model, there is a field called 'comment' and I referenced Comment model there. That way, every comment made on that post will be populated.

Now, if a user deletes any comment, that comments get deleted but the id referenced in the Post Model still remains. Though it is not active but it remains there. In a situation where you have many comments that get deleted, that Post collection with the Comment referenced field will look messy. Is there a way around this? I want once a comment is deleted, it should also delete anywhere it is referenced. Here are my codes:

**Post Model**

```
//creating the user models for the database

 const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
   
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
       
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    postPhoto:{
        type: String,
        required:false,
    },
   username:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    categories:{
       type: Array,
    },
   comments: [{
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Comment',
         unique: true,
       }]
   
     }, {timestamps: true},

     );
    //exporting this schema
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**Comment Model**

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose to be used
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    commentdescription:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
   author:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User',
        
    },
   
 
  }, {timestamps: true}
  );
 //exporting this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**Codes that delete a comment**

```
//comment delete
router.delete("/posts/:id/comment/:id", async (req, res) =>{


try{
  
    const comment = await Comment.findById(req.params.id)
    if(comment.author == req.body.author){
        try{
           
            await comment.delete()
           
             res.status(200).json("Comment has been deleted")
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    else{
         res.status(401).json("you can only delete your comment")
    }
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}


})
```

**codes that populates comment in Post**

```
//Get Post
router.get("/:id", async(req, res)=>{
try{
    const post = await   Post.findById(req.params.id).populate('username').populate({
  path: "comments",
  populate: {
     path: "author",
     
  }
  })
```

See the attached image. You can see that comment field in Post collection is still with a comment ref that has been deleted. The comment is deleted from the Comment Collection. But I will also like to delete all places it is referenced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my main language is not English, so I apologize for that

Some things need to be corrected

**Post Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    postPhoto: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    // Commented for testing
    // username: {
    //   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    //   ref: "User",
    // },
    categories: {
      type: Array,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment",
        unique: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
//exporting this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

**Comment Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    commentdescription: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    // Commented for testing
    // author: {
    //   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    //   ref: "User",
    // },
    postId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema);
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const port = 3000;

var mongoDB = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);

const Post = require("./Model/Post");
const Comment = require("./Model/Comment");

// add post
app.post("/posts/add", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const post = await Post.create(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: post,
  });
});

// add comment
app.post("/comment/add", async (req, res) => {
  const comment = await Comment.create(req.body);
  const post = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: comment.postId },
    {
      $addToSet: { comments: comment._id },
    }
  );
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: comment,
  });
});

// get all post
app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
  const post = await Post.find({});
  res.status(200).json({
    post,
  });
});

// delete comment
app.delete("/comment/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const com = await Comment.findById(req.params.id);

  console.log("postid", com.postId);

  await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: com.postId },
    {
      $pull: { comments: com._id },
    },

    { new: true }
  );

  await com.delete();

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server connect");
});
```

1. Models are not smart to understand your intention that because you
   deleted the comment, they should be deleted from everywhere.
2. Computers are stupid, you have to explain to them face to face.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for trying to help me..I ran the code and I got this error: ReferenceError: findByIdAndUpdate is not defined
    at C:\Users\kings\Desktop\blogfullstack\api\routes\comment.js:80:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Comment: Hi, is it possible for me to access the code in git?

Comment: If you can not, give me 1 hour, I will write a similar code and give it to you @kinhs

Comment: Oh, alright. Thank you very much. I have not pushed it to git yet. Will wait for you then in an hour. Thank you once again

Comment: Hello, thank you for waiting , Answer edit , Please check if it works and let me know. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It didnt work. I don't think that I can get Post model params since the path is leading outside the params of the Post in contention. I am thinking of writing a separate code that will remove null ref and use useEffects in react to call it whenever the post params reloads. It checks for null ref. I dont know if this is possible. Let me try.

Comment: I hope you get the answer soon. This code works on my computer. See also Postman collection. Good luck https://github.com/mahdaviansam/stackoverflow-p1

Comment: Thank you very much. You added a new path to the post and comment routes called /add. Can I do without that? App already linked with react and changing path will mean changing so many things